Synchronized getter for `static final` singleton instances
TLDR: Why does the getter of a static final singleton holder need to have a synchronized modifier?
Spotbugs' SING_SINGLETON_GETTER_NOT_SYNCHRONIZED ("SING: Instance-getter method of class using singleton design pattern is not synchronized.") check, pointing to the SEI CERT MSC07-J rule, expects a synchronized getter even for static final fields. That is:
public class MySingleton {

  private static final MySingleton INSTANCE = new MySingleton();

  private MySingleton() {}

  // This method is required to have a `synchronized` modifier.
  // Otherwise, Spotbugs check fails.
  public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance() { return INSTANCE; }

}

Could anybody explain the necessity of synchronized here, please? Given INSTANCE is static final, I was expecting no need for synchronization.

I think this is a false positive.

Does this answers your question?

@RomanC, no? I cannot see any mention of access to static final class fields there.

As explained in this Spotbugs ticket, this is indeed a false positive, i.e., a Spotbugs bug. synchronized keyword is not needed for static final instance getters. On the contrary, adding synchronized keyword creates a synchronization hotspot, leading to scalability issues.
